# Quit app after window is closed in AppleScript

Tags: xcode, applescript

I've created an AppleScript app in Xcode and I would like to know how to get the app to quit after the window is closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a [applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW9) method in your AppDelegate, for example:

```
on applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed_(sender)
    return true
end applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed_
```