# Quitting an app using the Red X button?

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript

I've made my first Mac app and it only has one window and I want it to quit when your press the red button. This button closes the window as opposed to quitting the app at the moment and I cant seem to find a way to edit the behaviour of this button any tips? Note this is in Xcode 4 and is an Applescript based app.

Comment: @duskwuff This wouldn't work for an applescript app though?

Comment: Oh, I missed that detail. Never mind! No idea.

Comment: @duskwuff Its all good I forgot to include it thanks anyway =P

Answer (score 3):

I don't know AppleScriptObjC but here's how you do it in objective-c. I'm sure you can easily convert these.

Basically you don't have to modify anything. Just put this method in your app delegate. It is called automatically by the app when the last window is closed because it's an NSApplication Delegate method. There's many other NSApplication Delegate methods so you should look at those methods to see what else you can do. Good luck.

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication {
    return YES;
}
```

By the way, alternative methods would have been to use NSWindowDelegate methods. You just need to set your AppDelegate (or any other class) as the window's delegate with...

```
[[self window] setDelegate:self];
```

Specifically you could have used either of these NSWindowDelegate methods to modify the behavior of the red close button. For example you could issue the terminate: method of NSApp in there to do as you asked but you can do anything in them.

```
- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender

- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
```

But applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed: is the one you want. I just want to show there's lots of ways to accomplish tasks.

Congrats on your first app!

Comment: An option for AppleScriptObjC can be found here (NOTE it is just after the last window is closed, not necessary anytime the red x is pressed): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365737/quit-app-after-window-is-closed-in-applescript

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @regulus6633 did NOT work for me.  The Xcode build failed.

This is because, like the OP, my Xcode app is a "Cocoa-AppleScript" app, and the AppDelegate is written in AppleScript.

So, the solution is:

```
script AppDelegate

--- YOUR OTHER CODE ---

   --- QUIT APP WHEN WINDOW IS CLOSED ---
   on applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed_(sender)
      return true
   end applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed_

end script
```

I put this handler at the end of the script block, but it probably doesn't matter.

I found this solution at http://www.macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=117933#p117933